# Specific model association case in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I have 3 tables: proposals, items/proposals (items is nested inside proposals) and invoices.

I want to create invoices for those items in the proposals that got approved. How would the associations for these look like? Also, how would I set up the invoices form to choose only those items that got approved by the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating two different line items models for Proposal and Invoice.

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :proposal_line_items
end

class ProposalLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proposal
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_line_items
end

class InvoiceLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

You can consider having an "approved" attribute in proposal line items. In the invoice form, you can show proposal line items approved by the client.

The suggestion of having separate line items for Proposal and Invoice is based on ERP data modeling principles to maintain the integrity of Invoice.

**Update**

For example here are the sample migrations for the models suggested

```
class CreateProposalLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :proposal_line_items do |t|
      t.references :proposal, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :name
      t.integer :approved

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateProposals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :proposals do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class InvoicesController < ActionController
  def new
    @approved_items = Proposal.find(params[:proposal_id]).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1)
  end
end
```

You can iterate over the @approved_items in your view and display it to users.

V

Comment: Could you please guide me through on how to show only approved by client items in invoice form? Thank you V

Comment: If you have created model(s) as suggested, you can find line items approved using

    p.proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1).length

This will give you all the line items which were approved by the client.

Comment: So I have created the models as suggested. Where should I add the p.proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1).length . Should this be in the invoices show view?

Comment: I have updated the sample code with one assumption. You will call new method with  proposal_id as a parameter.

Comment: So I went in to change my InvoicesController and found that mine says InvoiceController < ApplicationController and not ActionController like your example. Is this right or do I have to go through a migration to create this new controller? Thank you and sorry for my lack of experience!

Comment: Also, I tried doing the steps you outlined but I keep getting an error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InvoicesController#new
Couldn't find Proposal with 'id'=

Extracted source (around line #17):
15
16
17
18
19
20
              
  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @  approved = Proposal.find(params[:proposal_id]).proposal_line_items.where(:approved => 1)
  end`

Comment: It should be ApplicationController. Usually, the controller name is pluralized from model Invoice which should be InvoicesController.

Comment: It should be ApplicationController. Usually, the controller name is pluralized from model Invoice which should be InvoicesController. You need to append the proposal_id to your get request which will be accessible in the action "new".

Consider checking out one of the "getting started" tutorials on Rails. Rails platform is very easy to learn once you wrap your head around basic concepts. You are almost there. Don't give up.

Comment: Do you suggest I study http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html ? Are there sections that are more necessary than others? If so which are the top 5 guides I should definitely know by heart. Thank you fossil!

Comment: Good choice. Sometimes, it may look counter-intuitive to go through all the sections as some of them are trivial for people with programming background. As you have already realized, Rails has an opinionated way of doing things and you need to get a hang of it. I am sure once you go through all the sections, you will be ready to take on bigger challenges. You have to brace yourself to learn continuously on job for next few months. You have interesting and challenging times ahead. All the best!